# JQuery not adding class when used with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have the following function in my Meteor project:

```
function populate(){
  //console.log(Calendar.find().count())
  var dates = Calendar.find().fetch();
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
        var today = new Date(dates[i].date);
        //console.log('tbody.event-calendar tr td[date-month="' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '"][date-day="' + today.getDate() + '"]')
        $('tbody.event-calendar tr td[date-month="' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '"] [date-day="' + today.getDate() + '"]').addClass('event');
    }
}
```

When I uncomment the console.logs I get the correct count and code such as: `$("tbody.event-calendar tr td[date-month="8"][date-day="26"]").addClass("event")` for the dates loops.

What's weird is that if I remove the variable in the jQuery and hard code a number (substitute today.getMonth() with 8 and today.getDate() with 1) the code works as expected.

What's causing my jQuery not to work with variables?

Answer (score 4):

Try without a space between `date-month` and `date-day`:

```
$('tbody.event-calendar tr td[date-month="' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '"][date-day="' + today.getDate() + '"]').addClass('event');
```

Comment: Wow, I had it without the space before and I added the space while debugging another issue... Thank you!